# ckeditor strips style attribute

Tags: drupal-7, ckeditor, sanitization

On uploading an image and setting the alignment to `float:right;` when it displays in browser the style tag is removed.

This seems to be a very common issue, but I must have read every thread on stackoverflow as well as many on lesser forums and the general consensus is that its down to the Advanced Content Filter and if I add `config.allowedContent=true;` to ckeditor.config.js or to custom javascript configuration textbox my problem will be solved. I have tried that and it did not solve my issue (I also cleared the cache each time I applied a change).

I have also added `<style>` to `Home » Administration » Configuration » Content authoring » Text formats` but this has had no effect.

After reading the documentation and rereading the documentation I have drawn a blank and hope someone could offer a solution, in the form of a  plugin or a line/block of code.

Comment: have you tried to change drupal text format options?

Comment: No. This is my first play with drupal and was not aware of them. I will have a try and update with the result